Padding and decoration
im a UI-Designer who is trying to code with flutter (no experience yet, learning with the internet).
i try to code a segmented control, which shall look like this:  enter image description here
After hours i came that far:
 isSelected: isSelected,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        //selectedBorderColor: burple,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              color: isSelected[0] == false ? black3 : null,
                              gradient: isSelected[0] == true
                                  ? primaryGradient
                                  : null,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                            child: const Center(child: Text('Events')),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              color: isSelected[1] == false ? black3 : null,
                              gradient: isSelected[1] == true
                                  ? primaryGradient
                                  : null,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(12),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(12)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                            child: const Center(child: Text('Bars')),

But it looks like that:
enter image description here
I dont get the idea on how to add those to inner shadows (to make it look like a 3D-Pill) and How to get the padding between the borders. Sorry for the bad quality, im still fighting with the resolution of android studio.
I tried this, but the shadow is always outside and not inner:
Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      color: isSelected[0] == false ? black3 : null,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      boxShadow: isSelected[0] == true
          ? [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                blurRadius: 4.0,
              ),
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                offset: Offset(-2.0, -2.0),
                blurRadius: 4.0,
              ),
            ]
          : null,
    ),

For the padding i had literally no idea

'padding' is used to add space around the child widget within its parent widget.
You can wrap main container like this to give shadow as image.
 Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0x1A000000)),
              child: Align(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                   your container with segmented control
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),



One way of achieving this using TabBar

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

final String title;

@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
late TabController _tabController;

@override
void initState() {
_tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.black87,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Container(
              height: 36,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                  10.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: TabBar(
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
                  isScrollable: false,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                  // give the indicator a decoration (color and border radius)
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                      16.0,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  ),
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  ),
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Events',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Bars',
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}


